# Setting up Django with GeoDjango Support in AWS Beanstalk or EC2 Instance

Tags: postgresql, postgis, gdal, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, geodjango

So I have at one point had this going via Beanstalk, using Amazon Instance (2013.09) ami-35792c5c . At the time this ebextension scripts worked great when placed in the root of your repo in .ebextensions/

00_repo.config

```
packages:
    rpm:
        pgdg-redhat93-9.3-1: 'http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm'
        remi: 'http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm'

files:
    "/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-93-redhat.repo":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            [pgdg93]
            name=PostgreSQL 9.3 $releasever - $basearch
            baseurl=http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-$basearch
            enabled=1
            gpgcheck=1
            gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG-93

            [pgdg93-source]
            name=PostgreSQL 9.3 $releasever - $basearch - Source
            failovermethod=priority
            baseurl=http://yum.postgresql.org/srpms/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-$basearch
            enabled=0
            gpgcheck=1
            gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG-93


commands:
    epel_repo:
        command: yum-config-manager -y --enable epel

    remi_repo:
        command: yum-config-manager -y --enable remi
```

01_app.config

```
packages:
    yum:
        libtiff-devel: ''
        libjpeg-devel: ''
        libzip-devel: ''
        freetype-devel: ''
        postgresql-devel: ''
        gdal: ''
        gdal-python: ''
        geos: ''
        proj: ''
        libmemcached: ''
        libmemcached-devel: ''
        cyrus-sasl-devel: ''
        zlib-devel: ''

container_commands:
    01_collectstatic:
        command: 'PYTHONPATH=.:..:../lib cd site/kpmkhv && ./manage.py collectstatic -c --noinput && cd ../..'
        leader_only: true
    02_syncdb:
        command: 'PYTHONPATH=.:..:../lib cd site/kpmkhv && ./manage.py syncdb --noinput && cd ../..'
        leader_only: true
    03_migrate:
        command: 'PYTHONPATH=.:..:../lib cd site/kpmkhv && ./manage.py migrate --noinput && cd ../..'
        leader_only: true

option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
      option_name: WSGIPath
      value: site/kpmkhv/wsgi.py
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles
      option_name: /static/
      value: site/kpmkhv/static/
    - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
      value: settings_prod
```

So now when I use the same instance and launch  my environment, I get this error regarding a dependency.

```
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-5.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg93)
            Requires: libpoppler.so.5()(64bit)
  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Looks like the same repo is now returning a newer version of poppler, it was 12.x and now its 22.x and gdal needs the old version.

I also tested this out on an EC2 Instance and got the same error.  But then I ran into this document from amazon on [locking an AMI to its original repository version](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#lock).

So adding this to User Options via the EC2 Console when you launch fixes the problem on EC2:

```
#cloud-config
repo_releasever: 2014.03
```

What is the best way to always have this option when your Beanstalk launches the EC2 Instance on your behalf? I read about cloud-init and perhaps a script deployed via ebextensions would be the best bet?

Any insight on this is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I thought adding releasever=2013.09 to yum.conf & running yum clean all would do the trick. It seems to work on Ec2 @ ssh but not via files in ebextensions

Comment: Next thing I will try is custom ami

Comment: Custom AMI with all the right packages for some reason goes to Red status right away, more yum related issues.

Comment: Here is a related question, with an option for creating a custom AMI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326294/

Comment: Cool thanks, I tried Custom AMI and working on this with Amazon. The instance looks good to them but won't start up on EB.

Comment: Still working on that custom instance, have a ticket open with AWS. The CloudFormation yum dependencies clash with those required by my application, specifically gcclib and openssl. Another viable solution Amazon offers, is to upload all required rpms to S3 and download them from there. When I have more information, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @psychok7 tried this solution but ended up with this error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877882/beanstalk-migration-failing-for-geodjango

Comment: I have moved away from Beanstalk since, now using AWS ECS so can't provide much else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I now have a working ebextensions workflow on 2013.09 stack ami ami-35792c5c. For the 2014.09 stack see the other solution. The solution below works with postgis by installing the needed gdal component, 00_repo.config needs to look like this:

```
files:
  "/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-93-redhat.repo":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [pgdg93]
      name=PostgreSQL 9.3 $releasever - $basearch
      baseurl=http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-$basearch
      enabled=1
      gpgcheck=1
      gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG-93

      [pgdg93-source]
      name=PostgreSQL 9.3 $releasever - $basearch - Source
      failovermethod=priority
      baseurl=http://yum.postgresql.org/srpms/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-$basearch
      enabled=0
      gpgcheck=1
      gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG-93

commands:
  epel_repo:
    command: yum-config-manager -y --enable epel
  remi_repo:
    command: yum-config-manager -y --enable remi

packages:
  rpm:
    pgdg-redhat93-9.3-1: 'http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm'
    remi: 'http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm'
    qt4-devel: 'http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/qt-4.6.2-28.el6_5.x86_64.rpm'
```

The 2nd extension stays in tact. This works on Amazon Instance (2013.09) ami-35792c5c, I haven't tried the newer containers yet with it.

**Alternative 1**:

If you want less dependencies on repos / rpms from the ebextensions file, you could upload all required rpms to S3 and update the ebextensions 'packages' to  point to your s3 rpms. Setup your S3 bucket for public get access using CORS headers.

**Alternative 2**:

Create a custom AMI where you compile all dependencies from source. This way there will be no rpm conflicts and you don't have to temper with the default repos supplied by the AMI you are customizing. See this answer:
[Configuring Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with PostGIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326294/configuring-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-with-postgis)

Also check out the tool I made:

https://github.com/radlws/django-awseb-tasks

Answer (score 3):

My solution to a 2017.03 image was to:

```
commands:
  01_yum_update:
    command: sudo yum -y update
  02_epel_repo:
    command: sudo yum-config-manager -y --enable epel
  03_install_gdal_packages:
    command: sudo yum -y install gdal gdal-devel

files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgihacks.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      WSGIPassAuthorization On

packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql95-devel: []
    gettext: []
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
    libffi-devel: []
```

Comment: Thanks @psychok7, this worked like a charm. But I skipped the `files:` directive. I don't think its necessary for running geodjango.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue on the 2014.09 stack, ami id ami-246ed34c and got around the problem like this:

1. I found and downloaded the required dependencies online [here](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=lib64jpeg8) and [here](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=lib64poppler5). These are the versions that work:

   - [lib64jpeg8-8b-5.1.mga1.x86_64.rpm](ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/mageia/distrib/1/x86_64/media/core/updates/lib64jpeg8-8b-5.1.mga1.x86_64.rpm)
   - [lib64poppler5-0.12.4-2.1mdv2010.1.x86_64.rpm](ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/Mandriva/official/2010.1/x86_64/media/main/updates/lib64poppler5-0.12.4-2.1mdv2010.1.x86_64.rpm)
2. Zipped both .rpm files
3. Uploaded the .zip files to S3 and make sure the server can access them.
4. Added to `ebextensions/00_sources.config` the following code:

   `/etc/mylibs/jpeg8/ : https://s3.amazonaws.com/path-to-first-rpm-file.rpm.zip
   /etc/mylibs/poppler/ : https://s3.amazonaws.com/path-to-second-rpm-file.rpm.zip`
5. Installed via yum in `ebextensions/01_packages.config`. I had to use these commands to be able to install them.

   ```
   commands: 
     jpeg8_repo:
       command: yum -y install /etc/mylibs/jpeg8/lib64jpeg8-8b-5.1.mga1.x86_64.rpm
       ignoreErrors: true
     poppler_repo:
       command: yum -y install /etc/mylibs/poppler/lib64poppler5-0.12.4-2.1mdv2010.1.x86_64.rpm 
       ignoreErrors: true
   ```

Comment: Cool thanks for the input. I tried using this method as well but ran into ebextensions not being able to install my rpms, although ssh'ing into the instance and doing it by hand using yum worked.  I'll try zipping it like you did.  BTW are you using the 2014.09 stack? Also what is the original source / version of the rpms you use? Do you have the public links to the rpms?

Comment: Yes, I am using the 2014.09 image. And the reason why you have to zip the files first, is because the "sources" step only allows compressed files. The links to the original rpm resources should be visible in step 1 above.

Comment: Ok I used them in the packages: rpms: step as you see below. For the rpm resources in the first step, which exact version did you use? The search returns many for each. Was it the top match for each i.e. lib64jpeg8-8b-5.1.mga1.x86_64.rpm, lib64poppler5-0.12.4-2.1mdv2010.1.x86_64.rpm ?

Comment: Good question. These are the names of the packages that worked for me: lib64jpeg8-8b-5.1.mga1.x86_64.rpm and lib64poppler5-0.12.4-2.1mdv2010.1.x86_64.rpm

Comment: Where in your ebextensions do you extract the files? How do they go from being zipped to just rpm in the commands portion of ebextensions?  The above fails at the commands step for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to get this to work on the 2015.03 image and PostgreSQL 9.4 with a suggestion I found on the PostgreSQL yum mailing list (http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1429688221.3808.17.camel@gunduz.org)

Specifically, I installed libpoppler straight from a CentOS 6 mirror. I also used Mike Edward's suggestion of the Amazon Linux specific pgdg rpm. In whole, it ended up being a rather simple solution, which looked like:

```
yum -y install http://yum.postgresql.org/9.4/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-94-9.4-1.noarch.rpm
yum --enablerepo=epel -y install postgis2_94 http://centos-distro.cavecreek.net/centos/6.6/os/x86_64/Packages/poppler-0.12.4-3.el6_0.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Did you try Mike Edwards solution?

Comment: I did. The first command mirrors his solution. However, the only difference between the two pgdg repo files is that the Amazon Linux one specifies $releasever as 6. I was still having the issue with libpoppler, as I noted in my comment on his solution, so I had to seek out an alternate package for that.

Comment: And also, as a funny coincidence, that mailing list thread I linked to is where they first discussed creating the repo RPM specifically for Amazon Linux.

Comment: For the record, it's still happening in 2016.03 image and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the 2015.03 image, I had good luck using this value for the pgdg repo:

```
pgdg-redhat93-9.3-1: 'http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm'
```

With that, I was able to install gdal without needing to bring in libpoppler, etc., as separate rpms from S3.

Comment: Thanks for your tip, I'll update to that image soon.

Comment: Using http://yum.postgresql.org/9.4/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-94-9.4-1.noarch.rpm I am still having the same problem with libpoppler.so.5

Comment: Hi guys do you mind sharing the conf file working with the 2015.03