# Beanstalk Migration Failing for Geodjango

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, gdal, geodjango

I want to deploy geodjango in aws beanstalk.

I have already tried this solution. It worked before.

```
commands:
  01_yum_update:
    command: sudo yum -y update
  02_epel_repo:
    command: sudo yum-config-manager -y --enable epel
  03_install_gdal_packages:
    command: yum --enablerepo=epel -y install gdal gdal-devel

packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    postgresql96-devel: []
    gettext: []
    libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
    libffi-devel: []
```

But right now it's showing this error.

```
AttributeError: /usr/lib64/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: GDALGetMetadataDomainList
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

Here is the full [error log](https://gist.github.com/nashmaniac/27eec92c495e45fc5dcd70601d9fec01)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like using `Django==2.2.1` messing the things. The current `requirements.txt` which worked is as follows:

```
Django==2.1.8
django-cors-headers==2.5.2
django-debug-toolbar==1.11
django-extensions==2.1.6
django-model-utils==3.1.2
djangorestframework==3.9.2
psycopg2-binary==2.8.2
pytz==2019.1
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

Comment: This isn't a long-term solution, just a workaround that will keep one from having the latest Django features and patches. See my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62943011/4185989) for how to have both the newer Django and GeoDjango working on Beanstalk.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue as well, turns out django 2.2 [drops support for GDAL 1.9 and 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/#id1), the EPEL repositorie has version 1.7. I ended up installing everything from source with the following script:

```
commands:
  01_execute_script:
    test: test ! -e /usr/bin/gdalinfo
    command:        "/tmp/gdal_install.sh"

files:
  "/tmp/gdal_install.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      # Geos
      cd ~
      wget -O ~/geos-3.7.2.tar.bz2 http://download.osgeo.org/geos/geos-3.7.2.tar.bz2
      tar xjf ~/geos-3.7.2.tar.bz2
      cd ~/geos-3.7.2
      ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-python
      make
      sudo make install

      # Proj4
      cd ~
      wget -O ~/proj-6.1.0.tar.gz http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-6.1.0.tar.gz
      wget -O ~/proj-datumgrid-1.7.tar.gz http://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-datumgrid-1.7.tar.gz
      tar xzf ~/proj-6.1.0.tar.gz
      cd ~/proj-6.1.0/data
      tar xzf ~/proj-datumgrid-1.7.tar.gz
      cd ..
      ./configure --prefix=/usr
      make
      sudo make install

      # GDAL
      cd ~
      wget -O ~/gdal-2.3.2.tar.gz http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.3.2/gdal-2.3.2.tar.gz
      tar xzf ~/gdal-2.3.2.tar.gz
      cd ~/gdal-2.3.2
      ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-python --with-pg --with-geos --with-curl
      make
      sudo make install

      sudo ldconfig
```

If anyone finds a better solution, please let us know, building everything from source can take more than 30 minutes depending on instance size

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62943011/4185989 for a similar but IMO improved solution.

Answer (score 1):

@Jorge Alfaro is right in Django 2.2 [dropping support for GDAL 1.9 and 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/#id1). I tried his solution of installing things from source in an ebextensions .config file, but at least on a small EC2 instance, it would time out even w/the max-3600-seconds setting. A more robust and quick-launching solution is recommended at https://github.com/vancityhuddy/aws-eb-gdal-example where you:

1. Create an EC2 instance that you're able to SSH into, and which has permissions to push to an S3 bucket.
2. Use a [build script](https://github.com/vancityhuddy/aws-eb-gdal-example/blob/master/gdal-build-script.sh) on the instance to build Geos, Proj4, and GDAL locally.

   - Don't rely on that repo's specific numbers for those versions - reference [Django's site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/) regarding versions that are compatible with your version of Django.
   - For max reliability down the road, it's also advisable to modify the script to reference the datumgrid files as [Django's site advises](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#proj4).
   - Also note that the author of that build script mistakenly put Proj4 build twice. Ref the [needed edit](https://github.com/vancityhuddy/aws-eb-gdal-example/issues/1).
3. Push the builds to your S3 bucket.
4. Stop and terminate the instance you created in #1 if you don't need it anymore.
5. [Update your Beanstalk config](https://github.com/vancityhuddy/aws-eb-gdal-example/blob/master/.ebextensions/02_python.config) to download the builds from S3 and rely on them for your GDAL setup.

   - The PYTHONPATH in that repo didn't work for me - you may need to update it, e.g. /opt/python/current/app
   - If you had a previously functioning version of GeoDjango on your server via yum, for example, you probably will want to update your Beanstalk deployment settings to use the `immutable` strategy via the EB console so that this new install is totally fresh. Otherwise using the rolling deployments you're installing different versions of GeoDjango on the same server, and that caused errors in my experience (e.g. the OP's original `GDALGetMetadataDomainList`).

Comment: THANK YOU so much for this, you have saved me hours of work! For anyone else still struggling, a couple of additional things I found helped:
- Use the `aws s3 cp` command instead of `s3cmd` as the latter is no longer supported 
- If you can't get your permissions sorted between EC2 and S3 for the put request, use your access and secret key as follows: `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=access-key AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=secret-key aws s3 cp /tmp/gdal-2.4.4.tar.gz s3://my-bucket-name`