# install gdal on eb create/deploy failing

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, gdal

I'm trying to get my Django app live through AWS EB but when I follow the steps shown on the tutorial, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html, it keeps giving me an error saying "your requirements.txt is invalid." I think I'm getting error when it's trying to install GDAL 2.1.0 I have on requirements.txt

here are some of the config files I have:

**project.config**

```
option_settings:
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "hungryboat.settings"
        PYTHONPATH: "/opt/python/current/app/src:$PYTHONPATH"
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
        WSGIPath: "hungryboat/wsgi.py"
command:
    01_pip_update:
        command:"pip install --upgrade pip"
```

**packages.config**

```
packages:
    yum:
        git: []
        libtiff-devel: []
        libjpeg-turbo-devel: []
        libzip-devel: []
        freetype-devel: []
        postgresql95-devel: []
        geos: []
        libmemcached: []
        libmemcached-devel: []
        cyrus-sasl-devel: []
        zlib-devel: []
command:
    01_gdal:
        command:"yum --enablerepo=epel -y install gdal"
```

and the error message/log I get:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-build-zju5440p/GDAL/setup.py", line 118, in fetch_config
      p = subprocess.Popen([command, args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
      restore_signals, start_new_session)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1457, in _execute_child
      raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../apps/gdal-config'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-build-zju5440p/GDAL/setup.py", line 166, in get_gdal_config
      return fetch_config(option, gdal_config = self.gdal_config)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-zju5440p/GDAL/setup.py", line 122, in fetch_config
      raise gdal_config_error(e)
  __main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../../apps/gdal-config'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-build-zju5440p/GDAL/setup.py", line 118, in fetch_config
      p = subprocess.Popen([command, args], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
      restore_signals, start_new_session)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 1457, in _execute_child
      raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-build-zju5440p/GDAL/setup.py", line 320, in <module>
      **extra )
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "<string>", line 15, in replacement_run
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 207, in find_sources
      mm.run()
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 291, in run
      self.add_defaults()
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 320, in add_defaults
      sdist.add_defaults(self)
    File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 130, in add_defaults
      build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
      cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
    File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
      self.finalize_options()
    File "/tmp/pip-build-zju5440p/GDAL/setup.py", line 195, in finalize_options
      self.gdaldir = self.get_gdal_config('prefix')
    File "/tmp/pip-build-zju5440p/GDAL/setup.py", line 175, in get_gdal_config
      return fetch_config(option)
    File "/tmp/pip-build-zju5440p/GDAL/setup.py", line 122, in fetch_config
      raise gdal_config_error(e)
  __main__.gdal_config_error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdal-config'

  ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zju5440p/GDAL
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
2017-02-01 06:13:28,277 ERROR    Error installing dependencies: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 22, in main
     install_dependencies()
  File "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py", line 18, in install_dependencies
    check_call('%s install -r %s' % (os.path.join(APP_VIRTUAL_ENV, 'bin', 'pip'), requirements_file), shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1 (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

any suggestion as for how to solve this problem is welcome.

just FYI: I have tried answer by radtek on this post - [Configuring Amazon Elastic Beanstalk with PostGIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326294/configuring-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-with-postgis) with no luck. Also tried others similar to his answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating a huge command on the package.config file

I added this line:

```
commands:
    01_gdal:
        command: "wget http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/2.1.3/gdal-2.1.3.tar.gz && tar -xzf gdal-2.1.3.tar.gz && cd gdal-2.1.3 && ./configure && make && make install"
```

Since then pip install GDAL works perfectly. hope this helps if anyone's stuck. Disclaimer: Might be different for people using different environment / settings / etc.

Comment: This works it can take 20-30min to compile gdal. One option is to start an EC2 instance from the AMI used by Beanstalk, do the setup as you stated, then create a new AMI for it and update the beanstalk AMI id to the one just created. Explained in details here: https://blog.maddevs.io/running-geo-django-on-elasticbeanstalk-fd7b9862fb2c

Answer (score 3):

It may be because of missing development packages. So you could try installing 'gdal-dev' like this

```
yum --enablerepo=epel -y install gdal gdal-devel
```